# Pandas Groupby result into a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say there is a dataframe with 100 records containing 4(or n) columns, example of dataframe below:

```
 id  target   col3   col4
 00     0      ..     .. 
 00     0      ..     ..
 00     0      ..     ..
 01     1      ..     ..
 01     1      ..     ..
 01     0      ..     ..
 01     1      ..     ..
 02     1      ..     ..
 02     0      ..     ..
 02     1      ..     ..
 02     0      ..     ..
 ..
 ..
```

Based on this dataframe I want to create a new dataframe that is a resultant of `group_by` on this dataframe and `value_counts` of a specific column (target).

I have figured out how to get those values(my current code):

```
for id, target in df.group_by('id'):
    print(id)
    print(group.target.value_counts())
```

Which give me the following output:

```
00
0    3
Name: target, dtype: int64
01
0    1
1    3
Name: target, dtype: int64
02
0    2
1    2
Name: target, dtype: int64
..
..
```

I am able to get these values but I can't seem to pass these values into a empty dataframe. I would like to create a new dataframe that represents this information in this format:

```
id   0   1
00   3  NaN
01   1   3
02   2   2
..
..
```

Comment: am I missing something here or is what you want `df.groupby('id').count().reset_index()`

Comment: That gives a count of records for each key('id'). What I'm looking for is the count of each unique value for a column('target') for each key('key').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
df = (df
     .groupby('id')
     .apply(lambda f: f['target'].value_counts().to_frame())
     .unstack()
     .reset_index())

df.columns = ['id', 0, 1]
print(df)

   id    0    1
0   0  3.0  NaN
1   1  1.0  3.0
2   2  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do simple `.pivot_table()` with `'size'` as aggfunc:

```
d = {'id': ['00', '00', '00', '01', '01', '01', '01', '02', '02', '02', '02'],
     'target': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print( df.pivot_table(columns='target', index='id', aggfunc='size') )
```

Prints:

```
target    0    1
id              
00      3.0  NaN
01      1.0  3.0
02      2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas CrossTab functionality to achieve this. Pandas Crosstab computes the frequency of values between two factors in a table. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'id': ['00', '00', '00', '01', '01', '01', '01', '02', '02', '02', '02'],
     'target': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print ( pd.crosstab(index=df['id'], columns=df['target']).replace(0, np.nan) )
```

prints

```
target  0   1
id  
00      3   0
01      1   3
02      2   2
```